# Restar fechas en sql server resultado en años,meses,dias y horas

Tags: sql-server, trigger, datetime

Buenas tardes compañeros tengo en sql  un trigger que contiene esta consulta que me da el resultado en horas de la resta de dos fechas tiempo = 0y, 5m, 4d, 8h, pero necesito que el resultado me lo de en años, meses, dias y horas y que no lo redondee:

```
tiempotranscurrido = DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechacompra, fechapromesa) % 60;
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo del resultado que quieres?. También vas a tener a qué te refieres con que no redondee

Comment: algo asi compañero (tiempo = 0 y, 5 m,  4d, 8h), lo que me refiero que no redondee es que lo que tengo ahora si solo han pasado una hora y media me pone que son 2 y no quiero que pase eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay una rutina muy interesante publicada en  [este](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e5a4474-31b8-4316-8a34-1e4a5572fb49/date-difference-in-dayshours-minutes-and-seconds?forum=transactsql) foro de Microsoft, le hice unas pocas modificaciones para adaptarla al español. Una aclaración importante, no te va a mostrar la cantidad de meses por que cada mes tiene una cantidad de días distinto, salvo que tomes la decisión de que el número se calcule sobre la base de un mes estándar de 30 días, y no sería muy complicado modificar esta función.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfDateDiff (
    @start DATETIME, 
    @end DATETIME, 
    @useUtcIfNull BIT
)

RETURNS @DateDiffTable TABLE (
    [TotalSeconds]  INT,
    [Years]         INT,
    [Days]          INT,
    [Hours]         INT,
    [Minutes]       INT,
    [Seconds]       INT,
    [Description]   VARCHAR(100),
    [ShortDescription] VARCHAR(50))

AS

/*  DATE        AUTHOR              COMMENT
    1/3/2014    Monte               initial creation

    DESCRIPTION
        Returns properties describing the total amount of time between two dates.

    PARAMETERS
        @start => Optional.  The start date of the timespan to compare.  If this is NULL, the current UTC date/time will be used.
        @end   => Optional.  The end date of the timespan to compare.  If this is NULL, the current UTC date/time will be used.

    EXECUTION SAMPLES
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff(NULL, NULL, 1) --NULL values
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2010-12-25 00:00:00', NULL, 1) --time since Christmas 2010 in UTC
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2010-12-25 00:00:00', NULL, 0) --time since Christmas 2010 not UTC
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2010-12-25 00:00:00', '2014-01-04 13:32:10', 1) --span greater than a year
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2013-12-25 00:00:00', '2014-01-04 13:32:10', 1) --span less than a year
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2013-12-25 00:00:00', '2013-12-25 13:32:10', 1) --span less than a day
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2013-12-25 00:00:00', '2013-12-25 00:32:10', 1) --span less than an hour
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2013-12-25 00:00:00', '2013-12-25 00:00:10', 1) --span less than a minute
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2013-12-25 00:00:00', '2012-12-25 00:00:10', 1) --end date before start date
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2012-12-25 00:00:00', '2013-12-25 00:00:00', 1) --exactly one year
        SELECT * FROM udfDateDiff('2013-12-25 00:00:00', '2013-12-25 00:00:00', 1) --equal values
*/

BEGIN 

    /* DEVELOPMENT INITIALIZATION
        --DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME
        SET @start = '2014-1-3 13:13:10'
        SET @End = NULL
        --SET @end = '2012-1-3 00:00:00'

    --*/

    DECLARE @secondsPerYear INT = 31536000,     -- 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
        @secondsPerDay INT = 86400,     -- 60 * 60 * 24
        @secondsPerHour INT = 3600,     -- 60 * 60
        @secondsPerMinute INT = 60,     -- 60
        @totalSeconds INT, 
        @years INT = 0,
        @days INT = 0,
        @hours INT = 0,
        @minutes INT = 0,
        @seconds INT = 0, 
        @remainingSeconds INT = 0

    -- note: the ABS function is used to handle an end date that is before the start date
    IF @useUtcIfNull = 1
        SELECT @totalSeconds = ABS(DATEDIFF(ss, ISNULL(@start, GETUTCDATE()), ISNULL(@end, GETUTCDATE()))) 
    ELSE 
        SELECT @totalSeconds = ABS(DATEDIFF(ss, ISNULL(@start, GETDATE()), ISNULL(@end, GETDATE()))) 

    SET @remainingSeconds = @totalSeconds
    --SELECT @remainingSeconds AS RemainingSeconds
    SET @years = @remainingSeconds / @secondsPerYear

    SET @remainingSeconds = @remainingSeconds - (@secondsPerYear * @years)
    --SELECT @remainingSeconds AS RemainingSeconds
    SET @days = @remainingSeconds / @secondsPerDay

    SET @remainingSeconds = @remainingSeconds - (@secondsPerDay * @days)
    --SELECT @remainingSeconds AS RemainingSeconds
    SET @hours = @remainingSeconds / @secondsPerHour

    SET @remainingSeconds = @remainingSeconds - (@secondsPerHour * @hours)
    --SELECT @remainingSeconds AS RemainingSeconds
    SET @minutes = @remainingSeconds / @secondsPerMinute

    SET @remainingSeconds = @remainingSeconds - (@secondsPerMinute * @minutes)
    --SELECT @remainingSeconds AS RemainingSeconds
    SET @seconds = @remainingSeconds

    INSERT @DateDiffTable
            (
              [TotalSeconds]    
            , [Years]           
            , [Days]            
            , [Hours]           
            , [Minutes]     
            , [Seconds]     
            , [Description]
            , [ShortDescription]    
            )
    SELECT  @totalSeconds                                           AS TotalSeconds, -- including this because it's handy for sorting results
        @years                                              AS [Years],
        @days                                               AS [Days],
        @hours                                              AS [Hours],
        @minutes                                            AS [Minutes],
        @seconds                                            AS [Seconds],

        CASE WHEN @totalSeconds >= @secondsPerYear THEN CAST(@years AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' Años, ' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @totalSeconds >= @secondsPerDay THEN CAST(@days AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' Días, ' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @totalSeconds >= @secondsPerHour THEN CAST(@hours AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Horas, ' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @totalSeconds >= @secondsPerMinute THEN CAST(@minutes AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Minutos, ' ELSE '' END +
        CAST(@seconds AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Seconds'                           AS [Description],

        CASE WHEN @totalSeconds >= @secondsPerYear THEN CAST(@years AS VARCHAR(4)) + 'y ' ELSE '' END  +
        CASE WHEN @totalSeconds >= @secondsPerDay THEN CAST(@days AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'd ' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @totalSeconds >= @secondsPerHour THEN CAST(@hours AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'h ' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @totalSeconds >= @secondsPerMinute THEN CAST(@minutes AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'm ' ELSE '' END +
        CAST(@seconds AS VARCHAR(2)) + 's'                              AS [ShortDescription]

    RETURN;

END
```